# Is logic-heavy Promise chaining "callback hell"?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I launch my first promise and wait for it (this is the very high-level process of my system, it's where I chain everything together):

`install_demo_component.then()`, then, I need to handle the response from that:

```
install_demo_component.then(response => {
    if(response.failed) {
        undo_changes_we_did_from_install.then(response => {
            if(response.failed) {
                completely_uninstall_demo_component.then(response => {
                    if(response.failed) {
                        throw BIG_ERROR;
                    }
                }).catch(error => {

                });
            }
        }).catch(error => {

        });
    }
}).catch(error => {

});
```

But I can't avoid it. Nor can I make it prettier, me thinks. The way these promises are structured to wait for each other or start a new promise chain if `response.failed` arises is essential to how my system works, it's related to the business logic.

I think a lot of people would see this as callback hell and although I think callback hell in essence is something else, I agree it doesn't look nice.

If it really is callback hell, what's the alternative?

Comment: you can use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), that help to avoid callback hell

Answer (score 4):

## Original Answer

That isn't really promise chaining. To chain promises, you need to return a promise from the .then() method. I would rewrite your code like this:

```
install_demo_component.then(response => {
    if(response.failed) return undo_changes_we_did_from_install
    return Promise.reject();
}).then(response => {
    if(response.failed) return completely_uninstall_demo_component
    return Promise.reject();
}).then(response => {
    if(response.failed) throw BIG_ERROR;
    return Promise.reject();
}).catch(error => {
    //You only need one catch when promise chaining.
});
```

returning `Promise.reject();` will break out of the promise chain and jump to .catch()

Click [here](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) for more info on promise chaining.

---

### Error handling with promises

My original response was how to convert your code to a promise chain without changing it too much. I believe that's the best way to help people understand what was changed. However, I do have a suggestion on how you can use promises to their fullest.

Instead of checking for response.failed, you can have your asynchronous functions such as `undo_changes_we_did_from_install` reject on failure. This will remove the need for all of the conditional statements.

```
//The function below will either resolve() or reject()
install_demo_component.catch(response => { //Notice only .catch() is used.
    return undo_changes_we_did_from_install
}).catch(response => {
    return completely_uninstall_demo_component
}).catch(response => {
    throw BIG_ERROR;
};
```

You see .catch() is already invoked conditionally, the condition is if the previous promise rejected instead of resolved. And you see that the .catch() method can also be chained.

For a short article on this go [here](https://hackernoon.com/promises-and-error-handling-4a11af37cb0e).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid callback hell, all you have to do is run those install test inside of an async function. This can be done inside of an IIFE:

```
// returns a Promise
function install_demo_component() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({
      failed: false,
      func: 'install_demo_component'
    });
  });
}

// returns a Promise
function undo_changes_we_did_from_install() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({
      failed: true,
      func: 'undo_changes_we_did_from_install'
    });
  });
}

// returns a Promise
function completely_uninstall_demo_component() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({
      failed: true,
      func: 'completely_uninstall_demo_component'
    });
  });
}

// run install tests inside of async IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)
(async function() {
  // try/catch is used instead of the .catch() method when using async/await
  try {
    // using the new `...` from ES6 inside of an obj litteral, properties can be accessed from the function
    if({ ...await install_demo_component() }.failed) {
      console.log('install failed');
    } else if({ ...await undo_changes_we_did_from_install()}.failed ) {
      console.log('undo install changes failed');
    } else if({ ...await completely_uninstall_demo_component() }.failed) {
      console.log('completely uninstall demo component failed!!!!, What do we do?!!!!!');
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

}());
```

**EDIT**
Made the `if/else` logic make more sense based off of the order of actions needing to take place:

```
// run install tests inside of async IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)
(async function() {
  // try/catch is used instead of the .catch() method when using async/await
  try {
    // using the new `...` from ES6 inside of an obj litteral, properties can be accessed from the function
    if(!{ ...await install_demo_component() }.failed) {
      console.log('install succeed');
    } else if(!{ ...await undo_changes_we_did_from_install() }.failed) {
      console.log('undo install changes succeed');
    } else if(!{ ...await completely_uninstall_demo_component() }.failed) {
      console.log('completely uninstall demo component succeed');
    } else {
      console.log('Everything failed and now this sucker is gaana blow');
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

async await does wonders to get rid of all the trailing `});`

```
async function ur_func() {
    let response = await install_demo_component;
    if (response.failed) {
        let undo_response = await undo_changes_we_did_from_install
        if (undo_response.failed) {
            let uninstall_response = completely_uninstall_demo_component;
            if (uninstall_response) {
                throw BIG_ERROR;
            }
        }
    }
}
ur_func();
```

You could also use early returns to get rid of the indentation, but that's more a matter of preference.

Comment: Buuuuuuuuuut like...ain't that...the same thing just a bit nicer?

Comment: @coolpasta If "nicer" isn't what you're going for then what are you actually asking...?

Comment: @TylerRoper That's part of my question, sorry. Is callback hell a concern of aestethics or does it have practical implicatios (limitations, most likely).

Comment: The practical limitations are that callback hell is harder to debug because its harder to read. In terms of performance, awaiting a promise and using a callback are going to be the same speed